# Sum of Sequences in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

*(Disclaimer: This is a homework question.)*

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be sequences in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $X+Y$ converges. Prove or disprove that $X$ and $Y$ converge. Do we have $\lim (X+Y)= \lim(X)+\lim(Y)?$

I have a solution to this problem but I'm not quite sure if it is correct. Here is my solution:
$$X+Y = (x_{k}+y_{k})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\\\text{Let}\, \lim(X+Y) = (x+y)\\ \implies \forall \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists K_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N}\quad s.t.\,\,k\geq K_{\varepsilon} \implies ||(x_{k}+y_{k})-(x+y)||<\varepsilon\\ (\text{from triangle inequality)}\implies ||x_{k}-x|| + ||y_{k}-y|| < \varepsilon \\ \implies ||x_{k}-x|| < \varepsilon \quad \text{and}\quad ||y_{k} - y|| < \varepsilon \\ \implies \text{$X$ is convergent and $Y$ is convergent}\\ \text{with $\lim(X)= x$ and $\lim(Y)= y$} \\ \implies \lim(X+Y) = \lim(X) + \lim(Y)$$

Comment: In the simplest case when $n=1$ you have easy example $X_j=j$ and $Y_j=-j$

Comment: There exists counter examples, but where do I go wrong in my proof.

Comment: Fourth step is wrong. Norm of a sum is not equal to the sum of the norms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly the proposition is false. With $X=(x_k)$ and $Y=(y_k)$, let $x_k=k$ and $y_k=-k$, then $X+Y$ converges (it is constant zero) but both $X$ and $Y$ diverge. The same example also shows that $\lim(X+Y)$ may not be equal to $\lim X+\lim Y$.

The proof fails because the triangle inequality was applied in the wrong direction: $\Vert(x_k-x)+(y_k-y)\Vert\le\Vert x_k-x\Vert+\Vert y_k-y\Vert$.

Answer (score 3):

From the triangle inequality,
$$\|(x_{k}+y_{k})-(x+y)\|\le \|x_{k}-x\| + \|y_{k}-y\|\ .$$
If the LHS is less than $\varepsilon$, then the RHS (being bigger) is not guaranteed to be less than $\varepsilon$.

For example, $\|2+(-3)\|<4$ but $\|2\|+\|{-3}\|\not<4$.

So your argument is not correct.

In fact, the result is false - see if you can find an example.

Answer (score 2):

Try considering the sequences $(0,1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...)$ and $(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, ...)$. Both clearly don't converge because they alternate but their sum is a sequence of $1$'s.